# slideDown not working on <div> Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have it set to a div, not a span, I have the width and height of said div set in the CSS file, I think I have all the syntax properly set out, (since show/toggle work just fine), I just can't find a way to fix this. The  in question is contained within a div class="col-md-4" which is contained within div class= "container". The text is already hidden when you open the page, so that isn't the problem. Hence, I haven't been able to find the answers. I basically just want the website user to click "View details", have the div slide down displaying text, the button to change to "Hide details"(this part works fine), then the Div to dissapear again when "hide details" is clicked.

https://jsfiddle.net/LLdmvm7s/3/ on here it seems to work, animation and all, but on the actual webpage it just doesn't. There's no animation, the text doesn't show. I wonder if its the image? I don't know, I'm still a beginner.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#hiddentext1").hide();

    $("#button21").click(function(){
       $("#hiddentext1").slideDown();
       var txt = $(this).text();
       if (txt == "View details")
           {
               $(this).text('Hide details');
           }
       else 
           {
               $(this).text('View details');
           }
 }):
```

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

you miss `});` in the end

and there's a `:` which should be `;`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hiddentext1").hide();

    $("#button21").click(function(){
        $("#hiddentext1").slideToggle();
       var txt = $(this).text();
       if (txt == "View details")
           {
               $(this).text('Hide details');
           }
       else 
           {
               $(this).text('View details');
           }
    });
});
```

Comment: I didn't include the full code, it was just a rough copy-paste, but yeah I've got all that syntax stuff down- the animation still doesn't load. It worked on Jsfiddle so I'm wondering if I don't have Jquery properly linked or something. *shrug*